# Calling Class method on a potentially unknown class (iOS)

Tags: ios, class, methods

Assume that I have a particular class of object that defines a class method returning simple information about that class, thus:

```
+ (NSInteger) defaultValueForClass {
    return 5;
}
```

Now, imagine I have a series of subclasses, each of which overrides this method in order to supply different information. My question is this: how can I call that class method without knowing which concrete subclass is being actioned, in such a way that the relevant subclass method is used? I can't simply go:

```
[[anObject class] defaultValueForClass]
```

...because the compiler does not at this point know about my custom subclass method.

Comment: it will know the type of the class at runtime

Comment: It's not a question of what it knows at runtime, it's a question of making the compiler understand that this code is valid so that the project will compile in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about my previous post, I was wrong, just define a protocol and then check if your class conformsToProtocol, or check if the given class "isSubclassOfClass"

Comment: That seems to have cleared up the problem, although it appears that the original error I was being given was actually some kind of bug with Xcode. It's as if... this will sound weird but... it wouldn't recognise the class name until the class had been compiled, but the project itself would NEVER compile because the class name wasn't recognised. By removing the call to [class classMethod] and building, the compiler recognised the method. Replacing the code then ran with only cursory warnings that were cleared up by adding your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
// car.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject
+ (void)make;
@end

@interface Honda : Car
@end

@interface Porsche : Car
@end

@implementation Car
+ (void)make { NSLog(@"generic"); }
@end

@implementation Honda
+ (void)make { NSLog(@"Honda"); }
@end

@implementation Porsche
+ (void)make { NSLog(@"Porsche"); }
@end

int main() {
    Porsche *porsche = [[Porsche alloc] init];
    [[porsche class] make];

    Car *supercar = (Car *)[[Honda alloc] init];
    [[supercar class] make];

    return 0;
}
```

And the compilation and execution output shows no errors or warnings.

```
$ clang -framework foundation car.m -o car.o
$ ./car.o 
2012-07-01 01:53:46.559 car.o[8127:707] Porsche
2012-07-01 01:53:46.561 car.o[8127:707] Honda
```

What version of Xcode and GCC are you using? Is it the old GCC or the LLVM-GCC?

Comment: XCode 4.3
You know, the weirdest thing, I rewrote the code exactly as I first had implemented it, and it started giving a completely different warning! This cleared up straight away when I implemented Moxy's suggestion of making a protocol.